# Restaurar tamaño y posicion de una ventana WindowsForms en Multiples Monitores

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, app.config

Recientemente me he visto en la necesidad de que mi aplicación tenga la capacidad de poder guardar la información de la `Posición` y `Tamaño` de la ventana pero que funcione para mas de un monitor, es decir las ocurrencias que se pueden presentar al `minimizar` o `maximizar` la ventana en las pantallas.

> He visto varios ejemplos de como hacer esto **pero solo con un monitor**, por ejemplo [este artículo de CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/restoreposition.aspx?fid=1249382&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2595746) entre otros ejemplos...

Pero no se como hacer para que funcione en *varios monitores por ejemplo `2 Monitores`* , algo como:

- Poder comprobar si la ventalla esta parcialmente visible.
- Si esta sobrepasando los limites

**¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo lograrlo?**

> Visual Studio 2010 (C#) y .NET Framework 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado [esta respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942069/8933039) está en inglés.

**Código Original de la Respuesta:**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    bool windowInitialized;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // this is the default
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultBounds;

        // check if the saved bounds are nonzero and visible on any screen
        if (Settings.Default.WindowPosition != Rectangle.Empty &&
            IsVisibleOnAnyScreen(Settings.Default.WindowPosition))
        {
            // first set the bounds
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.DesktopBounds = Settings.Default.WindowPosition;

            // afterwards set the window state to the saved value (which could be Maximized)
            this.WindowState = Settings.Default.WindowState;
        }
        else
        {
            // this resets the upper left corner of the window to windows standards
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation;

            // we can still apply the saved size
            // msorens: added gatekeeper, otherwise first time appears as just a title bar!
            if (Settings.Default.WindowPosition != Rectangle.Empty)
            {
                this.Size = Settings.Default.WindowPosition.Size;
            }
        }
        windowInitialized = true;
    }

    private bool IsVisibleOnAnyScreen(Rectangle rect)
    {
        foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            if (screen.WorkingArea.IntersectsWith(rect))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);

        // only save the WindowState if Normal or Maximized
        switch (this.WindowState)
        {
            case FormWindowState.Normal:
            case FormWindowState.Maximized:
                Settings.Default.WindowState = this.WindowState;
                break;

            default:
                Settings.Default.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                break;
        }

        # region msorens: this code does *not* handle minimized/maximized window.

        // reset window state to normal to get the correct bounds
        // also make the form invisible to prevent distracting the user
        //this.Visible = false;
        //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        //Settings.Default.WindowPosition = this.DesktopBounds;

        # endregion

        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    # region window size/position
    // msorens: Added region to handle closing when window is minimized or maximized.

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        TrackWindowState();
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMove(e);
        TrackWindowState();
    }

    // On a move or resize in Normal state, record the new values as they occur.
    // This solves the problem of closing the app when minimized or maximized.
    private void TrackWindowState()
    {
        // Don't record the window setup, otherwise we lose the persistent values!
        if (!windowInitialized) { return; }

        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            Settings.Default.WindowPosition = this.DesktopBounds;
        }
    }

    # endregion window size/position
}
```

> Si para alguien mas es útil puede traducir la [Respuesta Original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942069/8933039)  y las explicaciones del usuario que contestó: [@Michael Sorens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115690/michael-sorens).